# Sonarqube bug, "Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to 'false'; some subsequent code is never executed". Whats wrong here?:

Tags: c#, null, sonarqube

```
IAlarmDevice alarmDevice = null;
 if(alarmFlag == 
     AlarmFlags.Acknowledge
    {
      alarmDevice = new 
     Acknowledged Armed Ice("Alarm1", 
     alarm.AcknowledgeCycle);
    }
 else{
      alarmDevice = new 
    ResetAlarmDevice("Alarm1", 
    alarm.ResetCycle);
     }

if(alarmDevice == null)
{
 throw new ArgumentException("Could 
 not create an Alarm device");
}
```

In the above code, the alarmDevice will get assigned in the "else" block if not the "if" block. In case even after assignment the value of alarmDevice is null( say could not find the alarm with the name passed in the constructor), the null check "if(alarmDevice == null)" will handle it. I don't understand why Sonarqube says that it always evaluates to false? It may evaluate to true in case  there is no alarmDevice with the alarm name string passed in the constructor in which case alarmDevice will remain null.
What am I missing here? Is it a sonar false positive by any chance?

Comment: "even after assignment the value of alarmDevice is null" - cannot happen. Either the object is constructed and assigned (and definitely not null) or an exception is thrown. There is no option for a constructor to fail and for null to be assigned to the variable.

Comment: You're assigning the value in the if and the else. How could that null check ever evaluate to it being null?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yep, the line "There is no option for a constructor to fail and for nu to be assigned to th variable" cleared it for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you remove all the noise, this is what your code comes down to:

```
if(...)
{
  alarmDevice = new ...
}
else
{
  alarmDevice = new ...
}
```

There is just no way in C# that `alarmDevice` could possibly be null. Constructors cannot return `null` in C# and so there is no possibility left to not have an instance assigned to your variable.

Comment: Yep, got it! I had the constructor throw an exception in case the alarm name is incorrect so i assumed the alarm device would be null in that case, but I understand that in that case the exception gets handled and the code flow moves to next code block. Thanks for the clarification!